# Somar os primeiros "n" elementos de uma progressão geométrica em Python

Tags: python

Um programa para somar os primeiros "n" elementos de uma progressão
geométrica, dados o primeiro elemento "a0" e a razão "r" entre os elementos.
Por exemplo, para n = 7, a0 = 1, r = 3: 1 + 3 + 9 + 27 + 81 + 243 + 729 = 1093

Comment: Tudo o que postou foi um texto que se assemelha bastante a um enunciado de um exercício, mas esqueceu de colocar o que já tentou fazer e descrever quais as dificuldades encontradas. Por favor, edite sua pergunta e mostre o que fez até agora.

Answer (score 2):

**Matemática [O(1)]**

O termo geral de uma progressão geométrica é dado por:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desta forma, a soma dos *n* primeiros termos ficaria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que, se aplicar o termo geral, obtemos a equação (1):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se multiplicarmos ambos os lado pela razão, *q*,  teremos a equação (2):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se subtrairmos as equações (2) e (1) entre si, teremos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que pode ser simplificada para:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Portanto, a função que retorne a soma de *n* termos de uma progressão aritmética descrita pelo termo inicial *a<sub>1</sub>* e pela razão *q* é:

```
def soma_progressao_aritmetica(n, a1, q):
    return a1 * (q**n - 1) / (q - 1)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/SadLimegreenOutsourcing) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/3GZsDS) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/83a47c7fe76a0cc890516af3875799b8)</sup>

Para chamá-la, bastaria:

```
print(soma_progressao_aritmetica(n=7, a1=1, q=3))  # 1093.0
```

**Laço de repetição [O(n)]**

Outra forma seria utilizando a função nativa `sum`, junto com um *generator inline*, que basicamente calcula todos os *n* termos da progressão e os soma.

```
def soma_progressao_aritmetica(n, a1, q):
    return sum(a1*q**i for i in range(n))
```

Obtendo o mesmo resultado, porém é uma solução que tem desempenho temporal O(n); isto é, o tempo de execução da função será diretamente proporcional à quantidade de termos somados, enquanto a primeira solução não.

Answer (score 0):

estou estudando Python e programação poucas semanas, mas tentei chegar numa solução. Não sei se é o melhor código, mas funciona.

```
n = int(input("Informe quantos elementos irá somar na PG: "))
r = float(input("Informe a razão entre os elementos: "))
primeiroelemento = float(input("Informe o primeiro elemento: "))

total = 0
pg = 1
print("Os termos da progressão são: ")
print(primeiroelemento)
for i in range(1, n):
    pg = pg * r
    print(pg) 
    total = total + pg

print("O total da PG é: ", total+primeiroelemento)
```

Comment: Se me permite o comentário, como está começando, ao invés de dizer onde há uma falha na sua solução, irei propor a você que insira um termo inicial da PG diferente de 1 e veja o que acontece.

Comment: Obrigado Anderson, realmente existe uma falha nesse ponto. Passou desapercebido nos meus testes. Irei verificar outra solução

Comment: O erro foi só que você iniciou `pg` igual a 1 e não igual ao primeiro elemento da PG.

Answer (score 0):

Se você pretende calcular a soma dos termos de uma `progressão geométrica` você tem que levar em consideração duas coisas:

1. A fórmula geral para calcular a soma dos termos da `Progressão Geométrica`;
2. Os tipos de `Progressões Geométricas`.

OBS: A partir de agora deixarei de utilizar o termo `Progressão Geométrica` e utilizarei apenas o termo `P.G.`.

A fórmula geral que serve para calcular a soma dos `termos` da P.G. já foi definida pela resposta anterior.

O que vou `enfatizar` aqui são os `tipos` de P.G.

Na matemática existe `4` tipos de `P.G.` e, cada uma delas podem ser definida em função de sua razão `q`.

1. `ALTERNADA` ou `OSCILANTE` (q < 0);
2. `DECRESCENTE` (0 < q < 1);
3. `CONSTANTE` (q == 1);
4. `CRESCENTE` (q > 1).

A fórmula definida na resposta anterior `abrange` a solução do cálculo da soma dos termos da P.G., exceto, no caso da P.G. ser `constante`.

No caso da P.G. ser constante, `(q == 1)`, a fórmula correta é:

```
Sn = (n * a1)
```

Onde `n` é o número de termos e `a1` o primeiro termo da P.G..

A partir dessas considerações desenvolvi o seguinte algoritmo...

```
from math import pow

while True:
    try:
        a1 = float(input('Digite o primeiro termo: '))
        if a1 == 0:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite números reais diferentes de "0"!\033[m')
        else:
            break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números reais!\033[m')

while True:
    try:
        q = float(input('Digite a razão da progressão: '))
        if q == 0:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite números reais diferentes de "0"!\033[m')
        else:
            break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números reais!\033[m')

while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Digite a quantidade de termos: '))
        if n <= 1:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite números inteiros maiores que "1"!\033[m')
        else:
            break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números inteiros!\033[m')

if q == 1:
    Sn = (n * a1)
    print(f'\033[32mA soma dos termos da P.G CONSTANTE é: {Sn:.2f}\033[m')

else:
    Sn = (a1 * (pow(q, n) - 1)) / (q - 1)
    if q < 0:
        print(f'\033[32mA soma dos termos da P.G. ALTERNADA ou OSCILANTE é: {Sn:.2f}\033[m')
    if 0 < q < 1:
        print(f'\033[32mA soma dos termos da P.G. DECRESCENTE é: {Sn:.2f}\033[m')
    if q > 1:
        print(f'\033[32mA soma dos termos da P.G. CRESCENTE é: {Sn:.2f}\033[m')
```

Observe o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/dymyodrm-solkarped)

É bom observar que este algoritmo além de calcular a `soma dos termos` da P.G., também as `classifica`.